# Unable to run the command cuckoo -d after installing the cuckoo

Tags: python, linux, github, sandbox, cuckoo

**ERROR I got is:**

> [cuckoo] CRITICAL: CuckooCriticalError: Unable to bind ResultServer
> on 192.168.56.1:2042 [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address. This
> usually happens when you start Cuckoo without bringing up the virtual
> interface associated with the ResultServer IP address. Please refer to
> https://cuckoo.sh/docs/faq/#troubles-problem for more information.

**The version of system:**

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS
Release: 18.04
Codename: bionic
```

For this issue I gone through the .conf of cuckoo like cuckoo.conf and vmware.conf files for IP address matching with vmware.

**Installing cuckoo steps followed are**:

1. Installing Python libraries.
2. Virtualization Software.
3. Installing tcpdump.
4. Installing M2Crypto.
5. Installing guacd
   Followed this [document](https://cuckoo.sh/docs/installation/host/requirements.html) for pre requirements installation of cuckoo.

After successful installation of requirements gone through [document](https://cuckoo.sh/docs/installation/host/installation.html)  for installing the cuckoo.

After installing during configuration that running cuckoo -d command there is error is occurred.
The error occurred in following this [document](https://cuckoo.sh/docs/installation/host/cwd.html#configuration) commands.

Steps I followed to resolve the error.

1. Gone through this [steps](https://github.com/CheckPointSW/Cuckoo-AWS/issues/8).
2. Made changes in the cuckoo.conf and vmware.conf files the IP address of resultserver.
3. The IP address is available and able to ping.

Still the error is not resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check `".cuckoo/conf/cuckoo.conf"` file?
Make sure the IP(under [resultserver]) has the private IP of your machine.

I traced that exact error location at the code (`cuckoo\core\resultserver.py`).

It is printing your error among with the IP as configured in cuckoo.conf.
Please make sure that you changed that at cuckoo.conf (as 192.168.56.1 is the default IP)

If there's still an error, then try searching the string '192.168.56.1' in cuckoo's directory so we will know where this configuration is coming from.